# Custom youtube player in android

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm trying to custom the youtube webview player in android with javascript, for first step I just added a simple button that pause the video, but for some reason it's doesn't response, here's my code:

```
public class CustomPlayer extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_player);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQfrTmubDzM?&autoplay=1&fs=0&rel=0&&theme=light&color=white&loop=1&showinfo=0");

        findViewById(R.id.btnPause).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:pauseVideo()");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this github source at https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player. Hope it will suitable for you.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i tried it already, but i want to make one by myself, i can't understand what im missing